# Complete list of graphics needed for iPhone app submission to the App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

Hello wonderful stackoverflowers!

I hope this question is within the scope of this site.

I'm preparing to submit my first iPhone app to the AppStore and I want to make sure that I have all the graphics needed. I also want to make sure that I have the required graphics for the iPad and **to be featured** (if I get lucky :).

Could we confirm that this list **looks correct and comprehensive**? Is there anything here **in excess or that neeeds to be added**? Any **warnings or caveats** from previous experiences?

Please keep in mind that I am looking for the widest possiblity of distribution.

For the sake of simplicity I'm going to submit everything as a .png. Would that be okay?
**If you provide large graphics for the Retina display on the iPhone 4 do you also need to supply the smaller ones? Likewise for the screen shots?**

iPhone & iPod touch

```
 1  57px     icon
 1  29px     icon-small
 1  114px    icon
 1  58px     icon-small
 1  640px x 960px screenshot 
 1  640px x 960px splash screen (in binary)
```

iPad

```
 1  72px     icon
 1  29px     icon-small
 1  50px     icon-small
 1  768px x 1024px screenshot
 1  768px x 1024px splash screen (in binary)
```

AppStore

```
 1  512px     iTunes Artwork
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for iPhone/iPod you needed
-320x480   screen shots

for iPad
-768x1024 screenshots

-512px     iTunes Artwork

icon files you don't need to upload while submission they should be in your project.

Answer (score 4):

Below is the resource needed before submitting apps to Apple store.

For Iphone

```
  App Icons (required)
      for 1x devices -  57 x 57
      for 2x devices - 114 x 114  (including iPhone 5)

  Icons for App store, called iTunesArtWork (required)
      for 1x devices - 512 x 512
      for 2x devices - 1024 x 1024 (including iPhone 5)

  Small Icon for spotlight search (recommended)
      for 1x devices -  29 x 29
      for 2x devices -  58 x 58    (including iPhone 5)

  Splash images (**required**)
      for 1x devices -  320 x 480
      for 2x devices -  640 x 960 (excluding iPhone 5)
      for 4'' screen devices (iPhone 5)  - 640 x 1136
```

For iPad

```
  App Icons (required) 
      for 1x devices -  72 x 72
      for 2x devices - 144 x 144  

  Icons for App store, called iTunesArtWork (required)
      for 1x devices - 512 x 512
      for 2x devices - 1024 x 1024 

  Small Icon for spotlight search (recommended)
      for 1x devices -  50 x 50
      for 2x devices -  100 x 100

  Small Icon for settings (recommended)    
      for 1x devices -  29 x 29
      for 2x devices -  58 x 58

  Splash images (required)
      for 1x devices -  768 x 1004 (portrait)
                       1024 x 748  (landscape)
      for 2x devices -  1536 x 2008(portrait)
                     -  2046 x 1496(landscape)
```

See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) , [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) if you want to get Apple's take on this.