# iOS: Screenshots appear to be edited with a noise filter after publishing.

Tags: ios, app-store

I've just noticed this today...

But I looked at the screenshots of my app in the app store, and they look like they've been edited with a 'noise' filter. I have supplied screenshots for the small and big iPhone screen for publishing.

When I view them on my mac, they look like intended. Do they need to be of another format, or did I forgot a step on the way? They are .png files.

Comment: you can search you will found many answers on SO, here is the one link http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/checklist.html

Comment: I really don't see anything on this website answering my question?

Comment: I told you to search too see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537030/complete-list-of-graphics-needed-for-iphone-app-submission-to-the-app-store

Comment: 1. This is off topic 2. This is impossible 3. Unless you can provide both screenshots there is not much to talk about

Answer (score 0):

PNG is the right file format for the app store. There is not much that could be wrong, maybe you have none or the wrong color profile embedded. The standard color profile should be sRGB for web-viewed images. How did you produce the screenshot files?  Could you provide a link to the app?